# Relative URLs in Quick Launch for Site Template

Tags: 2013, site-template, quick-launch

I'm putting together a site template in SharePoint 2013.

In the Quick Launch I want to add links to pages in the Site Pages library.

It seems there are restrictions to what can be entered as a URL:

[image]

If I start the URL with `/` I will need to enter the URL from the site collection level, but the site created from this template could be on a different site collection.

How can I use relative URLs so that when a site is created from this template the links work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out SharePoint is clever enough to know a Quick Launch link points to somewhere in the same web so when creating new webs from a site template the links still work.

I found this to be the case even when lists and libraries with the "Display this list/library on the Quick Launch" setting was set to No, and also with a Quick Launch link that pointed to a custom page in the SitePages library.

Comment: Yes. + I noticed that it works if You manually select target from "Browse" in Navigation "Edit link" widow. If You copy-paste relative address manually than this service could not work..

Answer (score -1):

You can use tokens in your URLs in the template, which will be replaced by SharePoint when you create a site from the template:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms431831.aspx

Comment: Tokens cannot be used in Quick Launch URLs. Please look at the image in my question.